# If $Y \subseteq Q$ is a retract of the Hilbert cube $Q$ and $Z \subseteq Q$ is homeomorphic to $Y$, is $Z$ a retract of $Q$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, retraction

For a topological space $X$ and its subspace $A$, we say that $A$ is a retract of $X$ if there is a continuous map $f \colon X \to A$ such that $f(x)=x$ for every $x \in A$.

The Hilbert cube $Q$ is the space $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ equipped with the product topology.

I'm trying to prove that if $X$ is a topological space homeomorphic to a retract of the Hilbert cube, then $X$ is a retract of every compact metrizable space it is embedded into. I would be able to prove this if I knew how to show the following:

If $Y \subseteq Q$ is a retract of $Q$ and $Z \subseteq Q$ is homeomorphic to $Y$, then $Z$ is a retract of $Q$.

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f\colon Q\to Y$ be a retract of $Q$, so such that $f(x)=x$ for any $x\in Y$.

Let $g\colon Y\to Z$ be an homeomorphism between $Y$ and $Z$.

If there exists an extension of $g^{-1}\colon Z\to Q$ to the entire $Q$, i.e., if there is a continuos map $h\colon Q\to Q$ such that $h(t)=g^{-1}(t)$ for any $t\in Z$, then you are done.

In fact the retract of $Z$ is

$$g\circ  f\circ h\colon Q\to Z$$

because for any $x\in Z$ you have

$$(g\circ f\circ h)(x)=g(f(g^{-1}(x))=g(g^{-1}(x))=x$$

Conversely, if there exists such retract $F\colon Q\to Z$, then $h:=g^{-1}\circ F\colon Q\to Y$ is the extension of $g^{-1}$.

Thus necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of this retract is that there exists an extension $h\colon Q\to Q$ of the homeomorphism $g^{-1}\colon Z\to Y$.
(For example this always follows if $g$ is defined like the restriction of $Y$ of an automorphism  of $Q$ sending $Y$ to $Z$.
Or for example the statement follows if $Z$ is dense in $Q$ and $Q$ is Hausdorff and first countable).

In general I don’t know if there is a counter-example of an homemomrphism $t\colon Z\to Y$ that is not an extension of a continuos map of $Q$ and such that $Y$ is a retract of $Q$.

In any case, as we discussed, your $Q$ is $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ and it holds Tietze extension theorem for $g^{-1}\colon Z\to Y\subset Q$, when $Z$ is a closed set of $Q$. In your case $Z$ is always closed. In fact $Y$ is compact because is the continuos image of $Q$ with respect to the retract. So also $Z$ is compact too, because is homeomorphic to $Y$. Hence $Z$ is closed too, being $Q$ Hausdorff.

Comment: I believe that the Tietze theorem shows that the extension always exists. Thus, the problem seems to be solved, right?

Comment: @jenda358 mmm I’ve thought before about Tietze theorem, but that one is formulated for functions that take values in $\mathbb{R}$, right? So we have to pay attention: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem

Comment: You're right, but fortunately, it is a well-known fact that Tietze works for $[0,1]$ as well.

Comment: @jenda358 and also for $[0,1]^N$, right? Should be in the equivalent statements of the link that I sent you

Comment: Yes, it definitely works for $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ as well, we just find the extension for each coordinate separately.

Comment: @jenda358 okay, top, so the statement holds if Z is a closed set of Q

Comment: @jenda358 I added the last part coming out from our discussion :)

Comment: The closedness of both $Y$ and $Z$ is automatic, becase both of them are actually compact. Being a retract of $Q$, the set $Y$ is a continuous image of $Q$, therefore (since $Q$ is compact), $Y$ is compact. Moreover, as $Z$ is homeomorphic to $Y$, $Z$ is compact as well.

Comment: @jenda358 ah yes, you are Absolutely right..more or less you answered to your question ahah 

Comment: Well, you made the key observation that the problem could actually be reduced to the problem of finding a continuous extension. Thank you very much!